# Reusable Alert Box, Which can we use through out Project?

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to re use the alert box which is in other class?

Comment: What is your specific problem with doing it yourself? If you need it done, you will need to hire a professional developer. But if you need help with doing it yourself, give it a try, post your best try here and ask a specific question about your specific problem.

Comment: hi @nvoigt, i tried many things but i didn't get any solution for this. That's why i posted a question for solution which i can used in all my projects coming. Thank you.

Comment: i changed my question, Please vote am unable to post other questions. @nvoigt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alert dialog

```
getCustomDialog({@required BuildContext context, @required String title, @required Widget body}){
 return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, 
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text(title),
        insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        content: Column(
           children:[
             body,
           ]
         ),
        actions: <Widget>[],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Use case:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      child: Text("test"),
      onTap: () {
        getCustomDialog(context: context, title: "test", body: Text("test"));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thaks for reply, it was showing error: The parameter 'context' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.

Comment: updated my answer please check and every field is required

Comment: how to use this?

Comment: you can call from a different class, where you use on tap

Comment: Please do not just do other people's jobs. This site is about *helping* other people with their problems, not giving them a complete solution. With a solution like this, they learn nothing and will just need to ask a question of the same kind for the next task they face. Wait for them to describe a specific problem and then help them understand it so they can do better next time.

Comment: Ok guys, @nvoigt. i will not repeat it again, i will try myself and learn new things. thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use an alert helper dart file. And here are functions in it. You can add title as you want.

```
void _showAlert({
  required String message,
  required String button,
  String? button2,
  required GestureTapCallback onPress,
  GestureTapCallback? onPress2,
  Widget? content,
}) {
  Get.dialog(
    SimpleDialog(
      elevation: 0,
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16).copyWith(top: 20).fit,
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                message,
                style: TextStyleExt.from(BkColors.blue113, 18),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              if (content != null) content,
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 16.h),
        Center(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              TextOnlyButton(
                button,
                onTap: onPress,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 8).fit,
                style: TextStyleExt.from(BkColors.redF50, 16).semiBold,
              ),
              if (button2 != null)
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12).fit,
                  child: TextOnlyButton(
                    button2,
                    onTap: onPress2,
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 8).fit,
                    style: TextStyleExt.from(BkColors.grey444, 16).semiBold,
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}

void showOkAlert(String message, [GestureTapCallback? action]) {
  _showAlert(
    message: message,
    button: 'Ok',
    onPress: action ?? () => Get.back(),
  );
}

void showYesNoAlert({
  required String message,
  required GestureTapCallback onYesPress,
  Widget? content,
}) {
  _showAlert(
    message: message,
    button: 'Yes',
    onPress: onYesPress,
    button2: 'No',
    onPress2: goBack,
    content: content,
  );
}
```

Comment: Please do not just do other people's jobs. This site is about *helping* other people with their problems, not giving them a complete solution. With a solution like this, they learn nothing and will just need to ask a question of the same kind for the next task they face. Wait for them to describe a specific problem and then help them understand it so they can do better next time.

Comment: okay, @nvoigt, you are right.